# How to fix SQlite Error in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda, homebrew

Im having a problem with SQLite3 in my environment

`ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/smol-cls-clustering/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension Referenced from: <C17E4304-87D3-3926-B99B-00758FBF13BB> /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/smol-cls-clustering/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-darwin.so Expected in:     <710E4989-2656-3774-8114-0C2936A8FC33> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`

I have tried `brew update/brew upgrade` and `brew doctor` but it did not fix the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now - `ipython` wouldn't start because of such import error. I ran `conda doctor` and found that `libsqlite` files had been modified somehow. Then I reinstalled it (`conda install libsqlite --force-reinstall`) and it was solved.